# Typesetting ZeroMQ in LaTeX

Tags: symbols

I'm currently typesetting [ØMQ (a.k.a ZeroMQ, 0MQ) project name](http://www.zeromq.org/)
using utf8 coding :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
ØMQ
\end{document}
```

is there any way of proper typesetting of project name, like with utf8, but without using utf8 ? (I've tried `$\varnothing$MQ` from `amssymb` package but it looks funny. `$\emptyset$MQ` does not look as supposed as well)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is the letter used in Danish and other languages ([see Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%98)), I would take `\O{}MQ`.